# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented - on using Touch Action

Tags: java, appium

I am getting above error while executing this code

```
WebElement radio = (WebElement) driver.findElements(By.tagName("option")).get(1);
radio.click();

TouchAction touch = new TouchAction(driver);
driver.performTouchAction(touch).tap(radio);
```

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 52 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Same here.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

This is the code I use.

```
TouchAction finger = device.touchAction()
            .press(width / 4, height / 4)
            .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(10000))
            .moveTo(width / 4, 60)
            .release();
    TouchAction thumb = device.touchAction()
            .press(width / 4, (height / 4) + 40)
            .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(10000))
            .moveTo(width / 4, 80)
            .release();
    device.multiTouchAction().add(finger).add(thumb).perform();
```

My device method that cast the `Webdriver` to the `AppiumDriver`

```
public TouchAction touchAction() {
    if (driver instanceof AppiumDriver) {
        return new TouchAction((AppiumDriver) driver);
    } else {
        try {
            throw new DriverIsNotAnInstanceOfAtriumDriverException(
                    "The driver is not an instance of io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver");
        } catch (DriverIsNotAnInstanceOfAtriumDriverException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm using Selenium 3.5.3 and Appium 5.0.3. What I have found so far was about wrong Appium Versions that I couldn't get rid of the problem.